# Generating Double-Triangular-distributed random variates

Tags: distributions, simulation, rejection-sampling, triangular-distribution

Wikipedia [shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution#Generating_Triangular-distributed_random_variates) how to generate Triangular-distributed random variates using a variate $U$ drawn from the uniform distribution.

A "Double Triangular" distribution is a special case of a mixture of two triangular distributions.  Specifically, it is determined by three numbers $a \lt c \lt b$ and a proportion $p$ with $0 \lt p \lt 1$.  It is supported on the interval $[a, b]$.

On the interval $[a,c]$ its density function is given by

$$f(x) = \lambda(x-a)$$

where $\lambda(c-a)^2 = 2p$.

On the interval $[c, b]$ its density function is given by

$$f(x) = \mu(b-x)$$

where $\mu(b-c)^2 = 2(1-p)$.

What would be a good approach to generating Double-Triangular-distributed random variates?

Comment: The double triangular distribution is described in this document: http://www.wsdot.wa.gov/NR/rdonlyres/BAB31979-0B6F-4AB7-841E-5666289A8021/0/RangeEstimating.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Following [whuber's comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber), here is a way to simulate from the mixture using a single uniform:*

Since the pdf of this mixture is
$$f(x)=p\dfrac{2(x-a)}{(c-a)^2}\mathbb{I}_{(a,c)}(x)+(1-p)\dfrac{2(b-x)}{(b-c)^2}\mathbb{I}_{(c,b)}(x)$$
the cdf is$$F(x)=p\dfrac{(x-a)^2}{(c-a)^2}\mathbb{I}_{(a,c)}(x)+\left\{p+(1-p)\left[1-\dfrac{(b-x)^2}{(b-c)^2}\right]\right\}\mathbb{I}_{(c,b)}(x)+\mathbb{I}_{(b,\infty)}(x)$$
Drawing a single uniform $U\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ and inverting the equation$$u=p\dfrac{(x-a)^2}{(c-a)^2}\mathbb{I}_{(a,c)}(x)+\left\{p+(1-p)\left[1-\dfrac{(b-x)^2}{(b-c)^2}\right]\right\}\mathbb{I}_{(c,b)}(x)$$produces a generation of $X\sim f(x)$. This inversion can be decomposed into two steps:

1. Determine if $u\le p$ or $u>p$ *[this is the decomposition of the uniform suggested by [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)]*
2. If $u\le p$, solve $(x-a)^2=(u/p)(c-a)^2$, namely take $$x=a+\sqrt{u/p}(c-a)$$
3. Else, if $u>p$, set $v=(u-p)/(1-p)$ and solve $(b-x)^2=(1-v)(b-c)^2$, namely take $$x=b-\sqrt{1-v}(b-c)$$or equivalently$$x=b-\sqrt{v}(b-c)$$

Interestingly, the last equation is *not* equivalent to
$$x=c+\sqrt{1-v}(b-c)$$because of the squared root.

Comment: +1 -- but I think there may be some inconsistencies in the factors of $2$ involved in $f$.  They disappeared when $F$ was introduced, but it could be a good idea to check that the algorithm is correct.

Comment: @whuber: thank you for pointing out the error in the factors 2. They now stand corrected. Hopefully.

Comment: @Xi'an you probably meant "the cdf is" in "the pdf is" (4th line)..?

Comment: Showing up 8 years late to suggest this is incorrect. You are essentially splitting the calculation in two for u <= p or u > p. But each part needs to work with a uniform sample in (0, 1). You are rescaling for the second case, but not for the first case. (2) should be x = a + sqrt(u/p) * (c-a)

Comment: @duncan: You are right, I forgot the $\sqrt p$.

Answer (score 3):

Rejection sampling is quite simple here (see the accepted answer or the end of this post for more efficient alternatives, though):

1. Build a rectangle around the density (which is easy here due to bounded support) - the green box in the figure.
2. Draw uniform variates in the box (so just two uniform vectors with the right suppport in both directions) - all the dots in the figure, both blank and red.
3. Keep those points which are below the density of the double triangular (the red dots in the figure).
4. Take the "$x$-axis" coordinates of these points as realizations of the double triangular.

In a picture:

[image]

Created with

```
a <- 0
b <- 2
c <- 1
lambda <- .5
x <- seq(a,b,by=.01)
ddoubletriangular <- function(x,a,b,c,lambda){
  p <- lambda/2*(c-a)^2
  mu <- 2*(1-p)/(b-c)^2
  return(lambda*(x-a)*(x<=c)+mu*(b-x)*(x>c))
}
plot(x,ddoubletriangular(x,a,b,c,lambda),type="l")
upperbound <- max(ddoubletriangular(x,a,b,c,lambda))
lines(c(b,b,a,a,b),c(0,upperbound,upperbound,0,0),col="green",lwd=4)

px <- runif(100,min=a,max=b)
py <- runif(100,min=0,max=upperbound)
points(px,py)

ikeep <- (py < ddoubletriangular(px,a,b,c,lambda))
px <- px[ikeep]
py <- py[ikeep]
points(px,py,col="red",pch=19)
```

Let's try more than just $N=100$ draws to study the quality of the algorithm:

```
N <- 1500000
px <- runif(N,min=a,max=b)
py <- runif(N,min=0,max=upperbound)
ikeep <- (py < ddoubletriangular(px,a,b,c,lambda))
px <- px[ikeep]
truehist(px,main="Rejection method",sub=paste("n=",length(px),"of",N))
lines(x,ddoubletriangular(x,a,b,c,lambda),type="l")
```

This results in

[image]

UPDATE:

As forcefully documented in the comments, the above algorithm is, being "off-the shelf", unnecessarily inefficient. Here is an illustration of what @whuber proposes (or so I hope):

*First improvement:*

Build two rectangular boxes and perform rejection sampling in each region separately (with probability $p$ for the first segment, and $1-p$ for the second), see the next figure. This by construction improves the acceptance probability to 1/2.

[image]

*Second improvement:*

Recognize that the regions in the boxes each are what @whuber calls "rectangular symmetric": the triangle above a segment of the linear density is a rotated version of the acceptance triangle below the density. Hence, we may use the "rejected" samples of the basic algorithm and use these as legitimate realizations for the other end of the segment.

For example, a rejected draw with $x$-coordinate $c+\epsilon$ may be used as an accepted draw for $b-\epsilon$, because the "height" of the rejection region at $c+\epsilon$ is by construction identical to the "height" of the acceptance region at $b-\epsilon$. This has the nice feature of increasing the acceptance rate to 100%.

Here is a way to code that:

```
a <- 0
b <- 2
c <- 1
lambda <- .5
x <- seq(a,b,by=.002)
p <- lambda/2*(c-a)^2
mu <- 2*(1-p)/(b-c)^2
ddoubletriangular <- lambda*(x-a)*(x<=c)+mu*(b-x)*(x>c)

upperbound1 <- lambda*c
upperbound2 <- mu*x[min(which(x>c))+1]

N <- 1500000
px1 <- runif(N*p,min=a,max=c)
py1 <- runif(N*p,min=0,max=upperbound1)

px2 <- runif(N*(1-p),min=c,max=b)
py2 <- runif(N*(1-p),min=0,max=upperbound2)

ikeep1 <- (py1 < lambda*(px1-a))
px1a <- px1[ikeep1]
px1b <- a+c-px1[!ikeep1]

ikeep2 <- (py2 < mu*(b-px2))
px2a <- px2[ikeep2]
px2b <- c+b-px2[!ikeep2]

px <- c(px1a,px1b,px2a,px2b)

truehist(px,main="Modified rejection method",sub=paste("n=",length(px),"of",N))
lines(x,lambda*(x-a)*(x<=c)+mu*(b-x)*(x>c),type="l")
```

Comment: Direct inverse sampling, as suggested in the question, would be simple and more efficient.

Comment: You are referring to the link to Wikipedia?

Comment: Certainly more efficient, yes. As for simplicity, which more subjective, the present solution avoids the need to compute the cdf (which obviously and admittedly is not difficult itself)

Comment: Wikipedia describes how to use a normal variate $U$ to generate a value from a triangular distribution. To generate a value from *any* mixture of distributions, assign the components to intervals $[u_i, u_{i+1})$ in a partition of $[0,1)$. Generate a single uniform $U$ and use that to select the component which contains it, say component $i$. Rescale $U$ to $(U-u_i)/(u_{i+1}-u_i)$ and use that to generate a value from the component. That requires so little extra work that it would take quite a stretch of the imagination to view it as being anything but the most simple possible approach.

Comment: I think that rejection sampling is a fine idea. What bothers me is that the implementation you propose is arbitrarily bad: when one triangle is long and low and the other is short and high, the vast majority of proposals will be rejected.  If, instead, you were to split the domain into the intervals $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$, and perform rejection sampling in each interval (chosen randomly with probability $p$), then the rejection rate would be $1/2$. With a tiny bit of cleverness (by exploiting the rectangular symmetry) you could change that into a procedure that never rejects!

Comment: Fwiw given the accepted answer I have made an edit that hopefully addresses your suggestion, and possibly even introduces a tiny bit of cleverness into my answer!

Comment: +1 Nice job!  This is now a great answer, beautifully illustrated.